# Codetrix capacitor google login expects options when signing in

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I created a blank ionic capacitor app and added the following package to enable google login:

> https://github.com/CodetrixStudio/CapacitorGoogleAuth

I followed the example there and I have the following:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import "@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth";

import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  userData: any = {};

  constructor() {}

  googleSignIn() {
    Plugins.GoogleAuth.signIn();
  }

}
```

But `signIn` requires an `options`. What do I need to pass?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass null and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the version you have to pass null or it doesn't requiere parameters.
If it's giving you the error "gapi it's not defined" i recommend you to see this comment in github:

https://github.com/CodetrixStudio/CapacitorGoogleAuth/issues/92#issuecomment-820808707

Basically one id on the tutorial/the code is misspelled and changing it would solve the issue.